# Find the value of $k$ so that one root of the equations $3x^2+7x+(6-k)=0$ is $0$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, quadratics

Find the value of $k$ so that one root of the equations $3x^2+7x+(6-k)=0$ is $0$.

My Attempt:
$$3x^2+7x+(6-k)=0$$

Now,
$$\Delta = b^2-4ac$$
$$\Delta=(7)^2-4.(3).(6-k)$$
$$\Delta =49-72+12k$$
$$\Delta =12k-23$$

....

Answer (score 4):

Because $x=0$ is a root, it means when you take in $x=0$ the equation is true. Hence, just plug in $x=0$, and solve the equation $6-k=0$ to get $k=6$.

Answer (score 1):

We can rewrite the equation as $$3x^2+7x+(6-k)=(x-0)(Ax+B) = x(Ax+B)$$ where $A$ and $B$ are numbers to be found, because $x=0$ is a root

We can then say $$3x^2+7x+(6-k)=Ax^2+Bx$$

We can equate coefficients to see that

\begin{align}3&=A\tag{$x^2$ term}\\
7&=B\tag{$x$ term}\\
(6-k)&=0\tag{constant term}\\
&\Downarrow\\
6&=k\end{align}

This method can be used for any value of the root $x$, not just $x=0$